# Can someone shortly explain the relationship between these two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

-I want to create a relationship between these two tables.

-As you can see that these two tables theoretical relate to each other.

-The ser_id of table two is to find in table one under the row 'value'. 
But only in the column with the name 'Apliance'.

-How do i build a reference and what type of relationship is this. For me is logical not possible to just create an reference between 'value' and 'ser_id'

-I am currently working with mysql workbench

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "what kind of relationship"?  What are examples of possible relationships?

Comment: The relation is: `WHERE T1.name = 'Aplicance' AND T1.value = T2.ser_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I mean with the relationship (1:n or 1:1 or n:m). I forgot to add that I want to create the relationship in the EER Diagram in Mysql Workbench iwant to make and relationship with these ''arrows''.

Comment: The design of table 1 doesn't look correct to me - shouldn't appliance/date/loadtime be columns for a single record? I guess you could have a theoretical relationship between these 2 tables but not one you could physicalise (in any database I am aware of). Relational models are agnostic to the values a column might contain - you can't define a relationship that only applies based on the values in a column

Comment: Why would you need to relate these tables? Table2 does not show any additional data.

Comment: Thank you made. I have another question but this is off-topic. If I have on Table with the information of the date. In one Table the information of the date is saved as ''date format'' and in the other, the information is saved in a ''varchar''. Can I make a reference.

Comment: I want to see  if every data von table2 are to find in table1.

Comment: Cannot link on or compare different field types. Would have to combine [date] and [time] fields and convert varchar value to date/time type. This is what calculated fields in queries are for - manipulate data.

Comment: Again, the tables are not designed correctly. You should not be holding dates in varchar columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, these tables don't really have a relationship, not as defined for a relational database.

If you only want to determine if each ser_ID in Table2 is found in Table1, do a "Find Unmatched" query by JOINing on Table1.value and Table2.ser_ID (date and loadtime records of Table1 will be dropped).

```
SELECT Table2.* FROM Table2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ser_id = Table1.value
WHERE Table1.value Is Null;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ser_ID NOT IN (SELECT [value] FROM Table1);
```

Table1 is an entity/attribute/value structure, although the entity is not clearly identified (possibly some event such as a test?). I will assume:

1. each sequential group of 3 records are associated with same entity and there are always 3 and only 3 records in each group
2. Apliance value is not repeated in Table1 nor is ser_id repeated in Table2
3. index is always positive and increasing.

Based on those assumptions, an Access CROSSTAB query using DCount() can rearrange Table1 data to normalized structure (irony is CROSSTAB usually de-normalizes data).

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.value) AS FirstOfvalue
SELECT DCount("*","Table1","[name]='" & [name] & "' AND [index]<" & [index])+1 AS GrpID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DCount("*","Table1","[name]='" & [name] & "' AND [index]<" & [index])+1
PIVOT Table1.name;
```

```
GrpID  Apliance     date            loadtime  
1      x4500    01.01.2005 14:00:00    44  
2      x4501    01.01.2005 14:00:14    60
```

A nested query can calculate a group identifier:

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table1.value, 
       (SELECT Count(*) AS Seq FROM Table1 AS Dup 
        WHERE Dup.Name=Table1.Name AND Dup.Index<Table1.Index)+1 AS GrpID
FROM Table1;
```

Unfortunately, using that query as source for a CROSSTAB fails.

MySQL does not have DCount() function. The nested query should be possible, however, I don't know if it can be pivoted because I cannot make it work in Access.

Alternative to CROSSTAB is to use nested query as source for aggregate query which calculates fields to emulate CROSSTAB:

```
SELECT Query1.GrpID, 
       Max(IIf([name]="Apliance",[value],Null)) AS Apliance, 
       Max(IIf([name]="date",[value],Null)) AS [date], 
       Max(IIf([name]="loadtime",[value],Null)) AS loadtime
FROM
       (SELECT Table1.name, Table1.value, 
            (SELECT Count(*) AS Seq FROM Table1 AS Dup 
             WHERE Dup.Name=Table1.Name AND Dup.Index<Table1.Index)+1 AS GrpID
        FROM Table1) AS Query1
GROUP BY Query1.GrpID;
```